# Evaluate $\int_0^2 (1+x^3)^{1/2} + (x^2+2x)^{1/3}dx$

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^2 (1+x^3)^{1/2} + (x^2+2x)^{1/3}dx$$

I figured out that the functions are inverses of each other (kinda). If find the inverse of 1st function, we get

$y=(1+x^3)^{1/2}$

$y^2=1+x^3$

$(y^2-1)^{1/3} = x$

But the function given is, $((x+1)^2-1)^{1/3}$

Substituting $x+1$ would also change the limits. So that is not possible. I don't know what to do here now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the question  ?

Comment: Find the value of the integral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Integral of Inverse Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) we have:

$$\int_c^d f^{-1}(y)\,dy+\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=bd-ac$$

given that $f(a)=c, f(b)=d$.

Let $f(x)= (1+x^3)^{1/2}$. As you have observed, $f^{-1}(y) = (y^2-1)^{1/3}$.

Also we have $f(0)=1$ and $f(2)=3$. Thus:

$$\int_1^3 (y^2-1)^{1/3}\,dy + \int_0^2(1+x^3)^{1/2}\,dx = 3\times2-1\times0=6$$

Do you see how $\displaystyle\int_1^3 (y^2-1)^{1/3}\,dy = \int_0^2 ((x+1)^2-1)^{1/3}\, dx$?

Comment: If they are equal, shouldn't it be just $2\int_0^2((x+1)^2-1)^{1/3}dx$? But that does not come out to be 6.

Comment: After a substitution of $y=x+1$, we still have $dy/dx = 1$.

Comment: I got really confused, I just saw what 2 functions you were showing to be equal. Sorry!

Comment: I would like to show what my friend proposed. It doesn't seem right, but gets the job done, He did $$x^2+2x+1 = y^3+1$$  $$\int_0^2 (1+y^3)^{1/2}dy + \int_0^2 (x^2+2x)^{1/3}dx$$ = $$\int_0^2 (x+1) dy + \int_0^2 ydx$$ = $$\int_0^2 xdy + ydx + \int_0^2 dy$$ = $$xy + 2$$. Plugging the limits $x=2,y=2 $ & $x=0, y=0$ The answer does come out to be 6. Is this approch correct?

Comment: I would say that it makes sense, and the approach is somehow similar to the solution above.